# Thee.js Material receive shadow has strange effect

Tags: three.js, shadow

I have little box mesh, and I am using `shadowSide: DoubleSide` for its material.
Then I just set `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` to true, but getting such strange effect:

[image]

If I remove `shadowSide: DoubleSide` I am not getting correct shadow:

[image]

Also, if I remove `castShadow` or `receiveShadow` from mesh, issue from first picture disappears.

So, what is the strange behavior on first picture when I use `shadowSide: DoubleSide, castShadow = true` and `receiveShadow = true` ?

Answer (score 0):

The strange behavior probably has to do with the fact that the shadowSide: DoubleSide causes the material to castShadows onto itself.

I wouldn't know why in the second picture it's not casting correctly. Might be something with the normals? The mesh doesn't seem like a three.js default geometry mesh, is it doing the same thing if you use a standard three.js box mesh?

Can you put it in a jsfiddle, that gets the results from above?